# Keras LSTM with embedding layer before LSTM layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying the example of keras IMDB data and the data shape is like this:

> x_train shape: (25000, 80)

I simply change the original code of keras example to code like this:

```
model = Sequential()
layer1 = Embedding(max_features, 128)
layer2 = LSTM(128, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True)
layer3 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
model.add(layer1)
model.add(layer2)
model.add(layer3)
```

The original model set `return_sequences` as `False` and I changed it into `True`, and I met this error:

> expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 1)

But I printed the structure of the model and found the output of LSTM layer is exactly a 3D tensor:

> lstm_1 (LSTM): (None, None, 128)

Comment: When you set return_sequences to true, you now have a many to many relationship. So each word in the sentence has an output value, vs just one output value originally when set to false, which is why you need a third dimension in the last layers output data

Comment: Yes, and the summary of the model can show that the output of the LSTM layer is (None, None, 128), but when it comes to fitting, it becomes  (25000, 1), which is quite odd.

Comment: you can use a keras reshape layer. I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334335/how-to-structure-an-lstm-neural-network-for-classification) a while back, and the answer is exactly what your looking for.

Comment: actually, I used a Flatten layer to solved the problem, and besides a reshape layer, a TimeDistributedDense layer after the LSTM layer, but the out put of this layer is still 80D vector so you still need a Flatten layer to connect it and the last Dense layer

Comment: You wouldn’t use a flatten layer before the last dense, this is altered by changing the Boolean value of `return_sequences`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your training array, use the below code:

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],1,x_train.shape[1]))
```

Also your testing array:

```
x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],1,x_test.shape[1]))
```

FYI: np is numpy pacakge.

Timesteps in LSTM models: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/

Timesteps: This is equivalent to the amount of time steps you run your recurrent neural network. If you want your network to have memory of 60 characters, this number should be 60.

Comment: I can understand that the train or test data should be shaped like this, but the embedding layer required the input be 2D tensor.
Besides, I was wondering why if we set return_sequence as False and only return the last output and the model can compile and go through the fitting.

Comment: Okay. So this is not only about reshaping, the addtional 1 parameter I have used is called timestep. For LSTMs you need to pass this parameter to tell your model how much set is required for learning parameters. I am updating my answer and will provide you a source which you can refer.

Comment: Ignore the time series just focus on why timesteps are required.

Comment: Let me know if you still have any confusion.

Comment: I know exactly why is timesteps required, but since there is a embedding layer before the LSTM layer, the data cannot be shaped in the form[samples, timestep, feature] but a 2D tensor.
Besides, when using return_sequences = False, the model is okay, so I suppose the model might use timestep=1 as default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a TimeDistributed layer after a LSTM with return_sequences=True

```py
layer2= LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, 
             recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True)
layer3= TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
```

Comment: Then it comes to the same error :
expected time_distributed_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 1)